# Wrong line after right click"inspect element" (selenium)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium

im new to selenium (and to html), and in the previous projects i used a bit of selenium when I wanted to select a dropdown value I just right click on the dropdown > "inspect element" and boom, i got to the line i needed which is always a  type.

but now I got to a different one, this is what i did:

[image]

and this is where i got:

[image]

Comment: First click on div element then click on item in list that you want to click

Answer (score 0):

*Dropdowns can be implemented in very different ways on a web page*. Sometimes there is no `select` element involved at all.

In your case, the `select` element looks hidden since it has `jcf-hidden` class and the dropdown itself is implemented differently via a `div` element with `select-area` class, and probably javascript is involved to read/update options from a hidden `select` element.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that it's the select tag you want, why not just use CSS selector to get that?

For example:

```
WebElement companyId = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("select#company_id"));
```

or

```
WebElement companyId = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.select-upload_company_id+select#company_id"));
```

depending on your need. The examples are in Java but can be translated easily to other languages supported by Selenium.